# Plot Color Discontinuous with Legend

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, color, legending

Im working on a project that simulates the temperature distribution within a material. Right now I have multiple plots using the ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap" and a legend on the side. It appears that each plot has its own color scheme that maps to different colors for their plot that behaves independently from the legend. The main issue for example is that blue could be 280 Kelvin in one plot and 300 Kelvin in another. I want all the plots to have the same constant legend and color scheme across multiple plots, so they make more intuitive sense to someone not looking as closely at the legend and to be able to simply see it visually.

PlotLegends -> Automatic, plots the correct values to the legend

```
(*Plotting*)
minTemp = 280; (*Kelvin*)
maxTemp = 340; (*Kelvin*)
legend = BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {minTemp, maxTemp}}];

SliceContourPlot3D[
 ufun[x, y, z], {"YStackedPlanes", {0}}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {L, 0, 0}}, r], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotRange -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20, ContourStyle -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x (cm)", Italic], Style["z (mm)", Italic], 
   Rotate["y (mm)", \[Pi]/2]},
 BoxRatios -> {0.5, 0.25, .25}, ImageSize -> {300, 350}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, 100 # // N} & /@ 
    FindDivisions[{0.0, L}, 2*Lo], {#, 1000 #} & /@ 
    FindDivisions[{-r, r}, 7], {#, 1000 #} & /@ 
    FindDivisions[{-r, r}, 7]}]
```

[image: Original Temperature Map]

But when enforcing a max and min temperature to the legend, it still plots the old scale on the slice which clearly conflicts with the actual temperatures and misrepresents the output. (Only edit made to the code is `PlotLegends -> Automatic` becoming `PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Right]`)
How can you get the plot legend to be constant range, while accurately linking the actual plot values to the color from the desired legend. Any help appreciated, thanks!

[image: Slice TemperatureMap Unchanged]

Comment: You haven't provided all of the code necessary to evaluate your code. However, use `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][(z - minTemp)/(maxTemp - minTemp)]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {minTemp, maxTemp}}]` to ensure that the functions are consistently scaled.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it ended up working out after a little maneuvering with your updated code. Sorry about just including the snippet and not the full code, I'll make sure to include everything for future questions.

Comment: @BobHanlon I know it's been a little while since you responded last, but would you mind explaining why that code was the solution to the problem of linking the bar legend and the graphs scales? More specifically, I'd like to know why you used [(z - minTemp)/(maxTemp - minTemp)] and how it works.

Comment: With default `ColorFunctionScaling`, variable's are automatically scaled to the interval `{0, 1}` to span the full range of `ColorFunction`. Each plot is scaled to its own `{min, max}` range. To share colors between plots, they must be manually scaled to a common range, and the `ColorFunctionScaling` must be set to `False` to turn off the automatic scaling. Above, `{minTemp, maxTemp}` is the common range and `(z - minTemp)/(maxTemp - minTemp)` scales the `z` values. Values equal to `minTemp` scale to `0`, values equal to `maxTemp` scale to `1`, others scale linearly between the extremes.